# How to handle closing window when pressing close icon on the top-right in WPF/MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling

I am able to bind buttons and menu items with `ICommand` and close the windows.
It is exactly as described in the tutorial [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) - via the `Command` property accessible in XAML.

But it is not described or implemented in the tutorial how to close by pressing the standard 'Close' icon on the top-right of the window. I need to perform some clean up in my application.
My question is how to bind a `Command` to the close event, so that it is executed when the user presses the close icon (not buttons or menu items - I know how to manage such cases).

How should this be handled to avoid violating the MVVM approach?
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/04/event-to-command-in-wpf-mvvm-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) contains a behaviour called EventToCommand, which gives you an easy way to bind a command to an event.

The following XAML snippet shows an example of how to get a command called "CloseCommand" to execute when the window's Closed event is raised:

```
<Window x:Class="EventToCommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">

    <!-- Make sure to put this tag directly inside the Window, 
         and not inside a child element, since it is the Windows that has the Closed event -->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <!-- Windows contents -->

</Window>
```

To get access to the EventToCommand behaviour, you need to download MVVM Light Toolkit from the [project downloads page](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases), and then reference the following DLLs:

- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll
- System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

That is all that is needed.

Further instructions of how to get started with the toolkit can be found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Erik. The main thing I know now that there is no simple solution without headaсhe from MS... as usual... And thanks for question clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

I would bind a Command to the Application's Exit event

I like using the `AttachedCommand` behavior found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/) for binding Commands to Events, although I know you can also accomplish the same thing using Blend's Interaction Triggers.